# sharing the memory of a program between ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, aws-ec2

Is it possible to combine the memory of ec2 instances? For example, let's say that I run a program that requires 2gb ram to run on one ec2 with 1gb ram instance,

can I somehow share that program's memory with another 1gb ram instance?

Comment: The operating system that you are running already does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to combine the memory of ec2 instances? For example,
> let's say that I ran a program that requires 2gb ram to run on one ec2
> with 1gb ram instance

No

> can I somehow share that program's memory with another 1gb ram
> instance?

No

These are separate VMs, highly likely to be running on separate hosts, in separate racks, possibly in separate data halls - you wouldn't *want* them to be combined, performance would be horrible - like tens of thousands of times slower than having one VM with 2GB.